# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING Gson, java, android

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

When I write this address: "http://mysite.test/?action=select" in Retrofit settings, Gson parser show this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
```

but I write this address: "http://mysite.test/mydata.json" then parsing passes successfully.

At address "http://mysite.test/?action=select" and "http://mysite.test/mydata.json" are the same data

Whhat is the problem?

Comment: share json and code

Answer (score 0):

In this string "http://mysite.test/?action=select" you are passing query parameters. While setting the address, Retrofit requires base address which will not contain any query parameter, only this part "http://mysite.test/" or "http://mysite.test/mydata.json". You can pass query parameters using @Query.